# How to make an Instagram gallery on a personal blog?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, instagram

I am trying to find and customize or build my own Instagram photo gallery for my personal blog website. The website is completely under my control (i.e. I can write PHP code server-side, etc.).

I've been looking around, and it seems that the Instagram API is centered around creating apps that need user approval.

I don't want to make a public app, I just want my own photos pulled from my own account without having to host them on my website directly.

I tried using the API, but my access token is apparently invalid. Is it possible to do something like this without parsing the HTML from instagram.com/my_account?

The closest I've seen to making this work is this site: http://intagme.com/ but they hide their source.

Answer (score 0):

The Instagram API is good, maybe you're doing wrong for that.

If you don't want to take images from the API, you can try this

```
<?php
    $homepage = file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/yourprofile');
    echo $homepage;

    // $images = explode('<td>', $homepage);
    // i'm not sure about the html structure of instagram website, but this will trace where is the image location.
?>
```

and then you can trace the image there,

you can run that on Cron Job, or every time someone open your website.

Comment: @Dagon i'm just giving him/her a solution without API

Comment: and im just saying its a bad idea, oh and against the sites terms

Comment: @JosuaMarcelChrisano that was my plan, unless I can find a way of doing this in a less hacky matter.

Comment: @Dagon granted, not the best answer, but no need to be rude about it.

Comment: if you do it remember you will be breaching Instagram's terms, which could get your account closed.